# In these 2 graphs, is x=2 an asymptote?

Tags: asymptotics, graphing-functions

Do these 2 graphs have asymptotes at x=2?

http://puu.sh/1aihI

In the second graph, IS THERE an asymptote?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st one does, 2nd does not. You should be approaching to infinity from both sides.

Comment: In the second graph, IS THERE an asymptote?